# AUCTeX View PDF Evince SyncTeX subdirectory

Tags: latex, auctex

I use LatexMK to output resulting files (including the .pdf and .synctex.gz) in the subdiretory `out`. But I also want to view the pdf and use SyncTex via Emacs and Evince.

One solution (see [here](https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk/issues/31#issue-276292840)) would require copying the .pdf and .synctex.gz after each compilation, but this is hacky. The comment afterwards ([here](https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk/issues/31#issuecomment-354862822)) recommends editing the `TeX-view-program-list-builtin`. This seems like a good approach, but sadly, evince uses a built in function named `TeX-evince-sync-view`, and I dont know how to modify the input of this.